# rollback whole txn when any of the insert statement fails in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I've a stored procedure where there are two insert statement for two different tables.

```
create procedure p_multiple_insert
(
// variable declaration
)
declare @temp int = 0;
begin try
    begin 
    // insert statement for TABLE1
        set @temp = 1;
    if(@temp = 1)
        begin
            // insert statement for TABLE2
        end
    end
end try
begin catch
// insert into error table error_number() & error_message()
end catch
```

If the error occurs with first insert statement block, `@temp = 0`. So second insert block does not execute and data is also not inserted in the TABLE1.

But if the error occur while inserting into TABLE2, how can I rollback my whole transaction. I mean roll back first insert statment too.

Comment: I think this question is what you are looking for: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/31279/transaction-and-try-catch-in-sql-server-job

Answer (score 1, accepted):

my changes are in UPPER CASE:

```
create procedure p_multiple_insert
(
-- variable declaration
)
declare @temp int = 0;

BEGIN TRANSACTION

begin try
    -- insert statement for TABLE1
        set @temp = 1;
    if(@temp = 1)
        begin
            -- insert statement for TABLE2
        end
    end

    COMMIT TRANSACTION

end try
begin catch

    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION

    -- insert into error table error_number() & error_message()
end catch
```

1. BEGIN TRANSACTION at the beginning
2. COMMIT at the end of try block
3. ROLLBACK everything in catch-block

My "Standard-Catch-Block" always looks like this:

```
    DECLARE @errmsg NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SELECT  @errmsg = 'Error executing dbo.StoredProcName: ' 
                         + COALESCE(ERROR_MESSAGE(),'No Message from SQL Server')
    RAISERROR(@errmsg,16,1)
    ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```